# VLCJ Mouse Event Input for Video

Tags: jframe, mouseevent, vlcj

So I have read some old posts (from 2011) that Windows has an issue supporting mouse events while videos were playing and some Windows hooker had to be used. Then, I found a more recent post related to this issue here: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/78

At the end of this post, a method to receive mouse click events is discussed and the developer of `VLCJ` himself endorsed it as the normal way to support the functionality:

```
Canvas videoSurface = this.mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface();
videoSurface.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Click");
        media_clicked();
    }
});
```

Except, when I tried it, it did not work.

```
package test;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        GraphicsEnvironment environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration graphConfigure = device.getDefaultConfiguration();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(graphConfigure);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(dimension);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent component = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayer player = component.getMediaPlayer();

        Canvas videoSurface = component.getVideoSurface();
        videoSurface.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Click");
            }        

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Click");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String currDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        player.playMedia(currDir + "\\sample_video_01.mp4");
    }
}
```

So the video is able to play, but no where in the console the phrase "Clicked" gets printed even with clicking on the screen while the video is playing. I have also tried `frame.getContentPane().add(videoSurface, BorderLayout.CENTER);` instead of `frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, but neither is able to print "Clicked".

I am using NetBeans with `jna-3.5.2`, `platform-3.5.2` and `vlcj-3.1.0`. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vlcj project issue page you linked to refers to another issue, and that issue has the answer, including a fully working test.

Essentially you must do this (on Windows):

```
player.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
```

And maybe this:

```
player.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);
```

What you're basically telling LibVLC here is "don't mess with the mouse (or keyboard) events" and send them to me instead.

This is not quite the whole story...

For keyboard events to be delivered you must manage focus correctly in your application. Clicking on the video surface does *not* (depending on your platform) automatically grab the focus.

One way to solve that is:

```
mediaPlayer.getVideoSurface().requestFocusInWindow();
```

This means when your window is focussed, e.g. by clicking, the focus will transfer to your video surface.

Here is a stable link to the test case:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.5.0/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/inputlistener/InputListenerTest.java

None of this is necessary on Linux.

Comment: It took me some time to try out your solution, but it really did accomplish the task precisely. I had to have both ```player.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);``` AND ```player.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);``` to get the coordinates - with either of them missing, it did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I m updating this for people who seeks this feature like me.
4 year after the api have changed a lot in the current update 4.2.0 that i m using you have to do the following

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mpc1 = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
mpc1.mediaPlayer().input().enableKeyInputHandling(false);
mpc1.mediaPlayer().input().enableMouseInputHandling(false);
```

as mentioned above this will disable handling in the vlcj video surface component, the later can be used as follow

```
MouseListener l = new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event detected mouseReleased");

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event detected mousePressed");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event detected mouseExited");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event detected mouseEntered");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event detected mouseClicked");

    }
};

mpc1.videoSurfaceComponent().addMouseListener(l);
```